# Is there a way to calculate the number of ticks it will take for a creep to get from A to B?

Tags: screeps

I know how to get the distance from A to B, but with all the terrain factors, its very difficult to calculate how long it will take a creep to travel that path. Is there a built-in way of doing this that I'm missing? Here's what I'm wishing for:

```
path = creep.pos.findPathTo(target);
creep.ticksForPath(path, {energy: 150);
```

where `{energy: 150}` allows you to force the calculation to use that amount of carried energy.

Is this possible or planned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing exactly available in the [game docs](http://screeps.com/docs/). But you could use the options `avoid` argument of the [findPath](http://screeps.com/docs/Room.php#findPath) function, to try and avoid swamp tiles. By default it favours least steps, fastest route anyway I believe.

There is a way to calculate the cost by finding a path and then comparing coordinates with a [lookAtArea()](http://screeps.com/docs/Room.php#lookAtArea) call.

```
var path = creep.room.findPath(creep, target);
```

`path` returns:

```
[
    { x: 10, y: 5, dx: 1,  dy: 0, direction: Game.RIGHT },
    { x: 10, y: 6, dx: 0,  dy: 1, direction: Game.BOTTOM },
    { x: 9,  y: 7, dx: -1, dy: 1, direction: Game.BOTTOM_LEFT },
    ...
]
```

You can then query top/left and bottom/right area with [lookAtArea()](http://screeps.com/docs/Room.php#lookAtArea):

```
var look = creep.room.lookAtArea(10,5,11,7);
```

`look` returns:

```
// 10,5,11,7
{
    10: {
        5: [{ type: ‘creep’, creep: {...} },
            { type: ‘terrain’, terrain: ‘swamp’ }],
        6: [{ type: ‘terrain’, terrain: ‘swamp’ }],
        7: [{ type: ‘terrain’, terrain: ‘swamp’ }]
    },
    11: {
        5: [{ type: ‘terrain’, terrain: ‘normal’ }],
        6: [{ type: ‘spawn’, spawn: {...} },
            { type: ‘terrain’, terrain: ‘swamp’ }],
        7: [{ type: ‘terrain’, terrain: ‘wall’ }]
    }
}
```

And then loop through the look for each path step you have and check on terrain type.

The 3 types we need:

1. Plain land – simple ground with a movement cost of 2
2. Swamps increase a movement cost to 10.
3. Roads decrease a movement cost to 1.

Something like (untested, incomplete code):

```
function terrainSpeed(terrainType) {
  var speed = 0;
  switch(terrainType) {
    case 'swamp':
      speed = 10;
      break;
    case 'normal':
      speed = 2;
      break;
    case 'road':
      speed = 1;
      break;
  }
  return speed;
}

// Traverse through path and check how many thicks it would take 
// based on carried energy and body
function calculateTicksRequired(path,look,energy,body) {
  var ticksRequired = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    var terrainForStep = look[path[i].y][path[i].x].terrain];
    var defaultTicks = terrainSpeed(terrainForStep);
    var moveCost = 1;
    // Perform calculation by looking at bodymove cost (based on body) 
    // and carry cost (based on energy)

    // LOGIC TO CALCULATE MOVECOST
    // ...

    // Multiply that by defaultTicks
    ticksRequired += defaultTicks * moveCost;
  }
  return ticksRequired;
}
```